Can I set a character limit for Toast UI Editor?
I have an application that is using Toast UI Editor to allow users to enter markdown. The markdown is stored in a database and there is a limit on the field length. So I would like to have some kind of validation on the client side that will prevent users from exceeding the character limit, something that works like the maxlength HTML attribute.
I've been unable so far to find any options for specifying this in the documentation. How can I set a character limit on the editor?

This is a basic implementation, and you may need to customize it further based on your specific requirements, such as handling different types of content or providing more user-friendly feedback.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var editor = new toastui.Editor({
                el: document.querySelector('#editor'),
                height: '300px'
            });

            var maxCharacters = 1000; // Change this to your desired character limit

            editor.on('change', function() {
                var content = editor.getMarkdown();
                var currentLength = content.length;

                if (currentLength > maxCharacters) {
                    // Trim the content to the maximum length
                    var trimmedContent = content.substring(0, maxCharacters);
                    editor.setMarkdown(trimmedContent);

                    // Optionally, you can provide feedback to the user
                    alert('Maximum character limit reached');
                }
            });
        });
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Toast UI Editor with Character Limit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editor"></div>

    <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor-all.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>




This is a good suggestion but it causes infinite recursion once the character count exceeds 1000. I think setMarkdown itself triggers the change event before the value is updated.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
